# How do I use AppleScript to close all applications that are hidden?

Tags: applescript, exit

I have an applescript made to close *all* apps:

```
tell application "System Events" to set quitapps to name of every application process whose visible is true and name is not "Finder"
    repeat with closeall in quitapps
    quit application closeall
end repeat
```

It works just fine. It quits all open applications.

My problem is that I want to modify this script to close only the apps that are hidden. For some reason, Apple hides all Apple-made apps with no active windows, and eventually it starts eating up my RAM.

What I *thought* was that if I just change the line `whose visible is true` to `whose visible is false` I would get that result.

Not quite:

[image: Weird pop-up window]

I don't even know what this window is supposed to be, so I just hit cancel.

Well, it pops up again. Turns out I have to hit cancel exactly four times before the script bombs out.

Is there any way to quit all hidden applications, while leaving open the visible ones?

(Bonus points if you can explain the pop-up above.)

If it makes a difference, I'm running the latest version of OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `visible` to false affects all processes – even processes / applications without a GUI. If a process is not an application (.app) the application chooser appears.

Add a check for `background only` which affects only applications with a GUI.

```
tell application "System Events" to set quitapps to name of every application process whose visible is true and background only is false and name is not "Finder" ...
```

Comment: This does exactly the *opposite* of what I'm looking for. It quit every application that was open and *not* hidden. I tried modifying the line to `whose visible is false and background only is false` and it did nothing. Modifying it to `whose visible is false and background only is true` just restarted my dock. All of them left the hidden applications open.

Comment: `visible` in System Events means `not hidden` and `background only` means faceless app without GUI or "not an app". Only applications (`.app`) respond to the `quit` command

Comment: Okay, but this still doesn't do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are talking about how when you press the red close button, it only closes the application's windows, but not the application itself, so it's just left there still open.

In which case, you can use this script I made, it seems it works flawlessly:

```
-- Get open apps
tell application "System Events" to set openApps to name of every application process whose background only is false and name is not "Finder"

-- Do this for every open app
repeat with openApp in openApps
    tell application openApp
        -- Tell application to quit if it doesn't have any open windows
        if (count of windows) is less than or equal to 0 then quit
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but when I run it it doesn't work at all. If the app is hidden, it still recognizes the windows as open. If all windows are closed but the application is open, the app still doesn't close.

Comment: Take a look at `openApps` and the `count of windows` with an application that is open but has no windows opened, tell me the results.

Answer (score 0):

OSX doesn't "hide" apps. They just aren't active, or don't have any documents open. Hidden apps is a very specific process usually done with Command-H. Apps don't hide themselves in this fashion.

Rather than trying to close apps with no windows, use the document count to determine whether to close an app.

```
tell application "SomeApp" if count of documents = 0 then quit
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirky issue. For reasons unknown to me, you have to separate stuff in order to get it to work. This quits every non-background app that's not in the igApp list. I added 'without saving' to deal with document apps like TextEdit but obviously, it's optional. While this could likely be streamlined somewhat, it seems to work reliably.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set igApp to {"Finder", "Script Editor", "firefox"}
    
    set qList to {}
    set fApp to name of every application process whose background only is false
    
    repeat with xx in fApp
        if xx is not in igApp then
            copy contents of xx to end of qList
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

repeat with yy in qList
 quit application yy without saving
end repeat
-- qlist
```

Note that if you want to quit some (or all) of your background applications you should probably reconsider. Those are doing things in the background and unless something goes awry, they generally don't abuse a computer's resources. Some may require force-quit to stop. If your computer is starved for RAM when it's idle, then either some app is broken/buggy or you need more RAM.

With that said, if you swap 'background process' to true, it should work on any of the background applications. As I said, I recommend against this but you could comment out the 'quit application' line and then uncomment 'qlist' (the last line), and then you'll get a list of those applications. You could look those apps up in Activity Monitor's Memory panel to see how modest these apps' demands are. On my mac, if you exclude obvious apps like 'Dock', combined they use < 200 MB of RAM.